# RealmModule gets replaced in the library

Tags: android, realm, mongodb-realm

MongoDB Realm: io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.16.1

I have a library which defines

```
@RealmModule(library=true, allClasses=true)
class LibraryModule() {}
```

and has a function LibraryDatabaseConfiguration() which

```
return new RealmConfiguration.Builder()...modules(new LibraryModule()).build()
```

In the application code

```
var database = Realm.getInstance(LibraryDatabaseConfiguration())
```

gives me access to the database with schema defined in the library - as expected.

In application after adding

```
@RealmModule(classes={storage1.class, storage2.class})
class AppModule() {}
```

and function AppDatabaseConfiguration() which

```
return new RealmConfiguration.Builder()...modules(new AppModule()).build()
```

function LibraryDatabaseConfiguration() returns configuration with **schema defined in the app** instead of library.

I verify this by iterating thru

```
database.getSchema().getAll()
```

The question is - how can I keep configurations in library using correct @RealmModule ?

*Submitted bug report: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7855*

Comment: Just a guess here but if your code touches Realm in any way *before* defines what classes to use (storage1 and storage2), all of the classes will be instantiated. So change the order in which Realm is being set up. It's also a good idea in questions to include you coding platform.

Comment: Thank you for the question, @Jay. I'm not sure what do you mean by 'touches Realm', but it always opened via configuration provided by the library itself.

Comment: "touches" means any reference to Realm in your code. I don't know your coding platform but this `@RealmModule(library=true, allClasses=true)` before this `@RealmModule(classes={storage1.class, storage2.class})` for example *may* cause  all objects to be built. That's purely an example and may not be the cause but the bottom line is that any access to Realm before stating what classes to use will cause all the objects to be built and therefore `.getAll()` shows all the scheme instead of just those two objects.

Answer (score 0):

The bug has been confirmed, workaround and work progress can be found [on github].[1](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7860)

Workaround: each @RealmModule class must have unique name.

Comment: please expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587